# change specific data of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which 10 record, now i want to update specific column data, means some part some column data and some not, for example in row 1 i want to change std with standard and other data will remain same, change same thing in all row in a single query. can it will be possible? and remember we cant remove and add cell again because it will change id

```
id - col1 - col2

1 - A - std abcad
2 - B - std bcddsad
3 - C - std avadsad
4 - A - std abcdsad
5 - B - std bcddsa
6 - C - std avadsad
7 - A - std abcdsd
8 - B - std bcddsds
9 - C - std avadsd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [replace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function for this

```
Update
    table
Set
    col2 = Replace(col2, 'std', 'standard');
```

Comment: Wait i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblName

SET Column .WRITE('Standard',(CHARINDEX('std',Column,1)-1),LEN('std'))
```